# Running inner function once on window scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that runs when scrolling through a window, it has 3 callbacks and is called multiple times with different functions passed, which is called is dependant on the amount scrolled:

```
var acc = 0;

function whileScrolling(callback1, callback2, callback3){

   if(acc > 0 && acc < 100){
      callback1();
   } 

   if(acc < 0){
      callback2();
   }

   if(acc > 100){
      callback3();
   }
}

$(window).scroll(function(){

    whileScrolling(func1, func2, func3);
    whileScrolling(func4, func5, func6);
    whileScrolling(func7, func8, func9);

    acc++;
});
```

Callback1 is handled as desired, however 2 and 3 are only to be run once (unless callback 1 has again been run in which case they may be run again). If I was only calling it once I could throw in some global booleans and run it like so:

```
var acc = 0;
var outcomeFlag = false;

function whileScrolling(callback1, callback2, callback3){

   if(acc > 0 && acc < 100){
      callback1();
      outcomeFlag = false;
   } 

   if(acc < 0 && outcomeFlag === false){
      callback2();
      outcomeFlag = true;
   }

   if(acc > 100 && outcomeFlag === false){
      callback3();
      outcomeFlag = true;
   }
}  

$(window).scroll(function(){
    whileScrolling(func1, func2, func3);
    acc++;
});
```

However each invocation of the 'whileScrolling' function needs to have its own set of 'flags', using globals for each will be very messy as this will be done a number of times - Is it possible to contain this behaviour within the 'whileScrolling' function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function that returns a function. The inner function can reference the arguments of the outer function. I don't know a better way to explain this, so hopefully this code is clear enough:

```
function configureWhileScrolling(flag1, flag2, flag3) {

    var outcomeFlag = false;

    return function (callback1, callback2, callback3){

        if(acc > 0 && acc < 100){
            callback1();
            outcomeFlag = flag1;
        } 

        if(acc < 0 && outcomeFlag === false){
            callback2();
            outcomeFlag = flag2;
        }

        if(acc > 100 && outcomeFlag === false){
            callback3();
            outcomeFlag = flag3;
        }
    }  
}

whileScrollingInstance1 = configureWhileScrolling(false, true, true);

whileScrollingInstance1(callback1, callback2, callback3);
```

Comment: Yep this works, would be nice if there was away of getting around declaring the 'whileScrollingInstance' each time (the flags will never be set to anything but false, true, true anyway so no need to pass these) but one extra line isn't too big a trade.

Comment: @yung-hans You can do `configureWhileScrolling(false, true, true)(callback1, callback2, callback3);` but this way, a new function will be generated everytime whileScrolling is called.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no better way as using globals since a function-intern variable will be redeclared each time the function is called. But I suggest simplyfying things using an object:

```
var outcomeFlag = {};
function whileScrolling(callback1, callback2, callback3){
    ...
    if(acc > 100 && !outcomeFlag[callback2]) {
        do your stuff
        outcomeFlag[callback2] = true;
    }

}
```